# UWP Composition API breaks Visual Studio 2015 Designer - Cannot load a reference assembly for execution

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, xaml-composition

When I create custom control that uses new Composition API from Anniversary Update, then Visual Studio Designer is broken:

[image]

However the application runs just fine.

Why is that? how to avoid it?

EDIT:
Please, vote on UserVoice ([Fix the UWP designer errors](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/18892300-fix-the-uwp-designer-errors)) so Microsoft will adress this issues finally.

Visual Studio 2017 is out for a while, two VS updates has been released and nobody adressing issues with UWP designer.

Comment: There are a lot of issues with the designer and the composition APIs. See https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/issues/112

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I partially solved the problem by using animation helpers and controls like DropShadowPanel from https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit and upgrading to Visual Studio 2017 and installing all updated and installing latest windows update (creators)

UWP designer sucks anyway, but at least some views works, when I do not use composition api directly.

If you are experiencing simmilar issues, vote on UserVoice:  [Fix the UWP designer errors](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/18892300-fix-the-uwp-designer-errors)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was adding an instance on my view model within the XAML file itself.

[image]

I removed that and the designer was back!